# How to stop tab bar extra feature in iphone development?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I am building an app in which user use app after sign in, this app is tab bar and i am using navigation in each tab bar item. The problem is when i move tab bar item 1 to 2 then 2 to 1 like first tab bar item name is game, and second one name is store, and in game tab bar user play game before sign in when i move from game to store then store to game it move back or `popviewcontroller`automatically, so this shouldn't happen in my app flow. How can i stop this or block this.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint when you switch tabs and observe in the debugger what happens. Insert `NSLog` statements at `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` to see what causes your views to pop.